# How do I extract transaction details from a redirected Payment Processor Site and save to my rails 4 db

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Am working on a Paid Ads Job Board. I have implemented a Nigerian Payment Processor (VoguePay) which provided no documentation on using its API on Ruby on Rails Framework to get details from transactions and do anything with it.

**Note**

VouguePay Payment Processor has a POST method with action redirecting to it payment website (https://voguepay.com/pay/) in order to be able to make transaction.

**This is what I have done such that the process is done inside my App**

I enclosed VoguePay API in an iFrame html tag such that the process is done on my app and not go outside my app to make payment.

> Below are my codes

**JobsController**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  layout false, only: [:voguepay]

  def index
    @jobs = Job.paid_ad
  end

  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @job if @job.paid?
  end

  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    if !(@job.paid?)
      @job.update_attributes(stripeEmail: params[:stripeEmail], payola_sale_guid: params[:transaction_id])
      # The "has_key?" Returns true if the given key/attribute is present in hash e.g.
      # h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
      # h.has_key?("a")   #=> true
      # h.has_key?("z")   #=> false.
      # So this means --Update job_params if the given key/attribute is present or not in job.
      @job.update(job_params) if params.has_key?(:job)
      redirect_to  preview_job_path(@job) #show_job_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    if @job.save
      redirect_to preview_job_path(@job)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def preview
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @job if @job.paid?
  end

  def payment
    @job = Job.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
    redirect_to job_path(@job) if @job.paid?
  end

  def search
    @jobs = Job.search(params)
  end


  def voguepay
    #Nothing here yet.
  end

  private

  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:title, :category, :location, :description, :to_apply, :email, :company_name, :website)
  end
end
```

**jobs\payments.html.erb**

```
<iframe id="vogueFrame" seamless="seamless" target="_self" src="<%= '/../jobs/shared/voguepay' %>"
        style="width: 100%; height: 1200px; align:center"
        scrolling="no"
        marginwidth="0"
        marginheight="0"
        frameborder="0"
        vspace="0"
        hspace="0">
</iframe>
```

**VoguePayForm which was rendered inside iframe src above**

```
<%= render 'shared/layout_for_voguepay'%>
<%= render 'shared/four_breaks' %>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-md-12">
    <p class="text-center"><strong style="font-weight: bold; font-size:20px;">STEP 3 (OF 3): ENTER YOUR CARD EMAIL & PROCEED TO MAKE PAYMENT</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
<%= render 'shared/two_breaks' %>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-4'></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 panel panel-default">
      <%#= render 'shared/two_breaks' %>

      <form method="POST" action="https://voguepay.com/pay/">
        <input type="hidden" name="v_merchant_id" value="demo" />
        <input type="hidden" name="memo" value="Payment for Far-Flung Jobs" />
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="http://localhost:3000" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cur" value="NGN" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_1" value="Job Ads" />
        <input type="hidden" name="price_1" value="3000" />
        <input type="hidden" name="description_1" value="FarFlung Jobs Ads Payment" /><br />



          <div class='form-row'>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
              <button name="submit"  type="submit" class="btn" style="color: #ffffff; background: #990099 none; border-bottom: double; margin-bottom: 13px;" id="submit" >MAKE PAYMENT</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**VoguePay Payment Network Log**

[Browser Network Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDcTV.png)

**My Question/Desire/What I like to do**

How do I extract transaction details from that redirected Payment Processor Site and save details of my choice to my Rails 4 database/table using **JavaScript** or **JSON**?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I write based on the feedbacks I got from the Technical team in response to the specific issues you raised, even though there is no specific application developed for Ruby on Rails yet. (Please note that we are open to developers who create third-party extensions on VoguePay)

**What You Should do?**

- Go to [VoguePay's developers' page](https://voguepay.com/developers).
- Click on the Notification tab.

[Click Here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDuBL.png)

- It shows you how to use the success URL link generated to redirect to your site/app.

Feel free to contact us on support@voguepay.com if any further assistance is needed.

Comment: I have done all written here, and that doesnt solve my problem. I did set my `success_url` with a routing as a POST method such that it links to:

`<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="http://www.example.com/thanks" />`

Yes, the `transaction_id` was posted to that URL checking my Browser Network Tab, but I can't still get it to fill my Database Table.

Comment: Since you don't have Rails Documentation, I think using JavaScript or JSON can help me.